# How to change export button to custom icon in highcharts

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

I am using Highcharts,Here I need to change the export button of right side into a download icon/image. Also Legends text like installation,Manufacturing color to same as particular series color,I mean same color as icons before legend text.Here is the code below

### html

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

### script.js

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change an exporting button by editing `contextButton` properties:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            symbol: 'circle',
            symbolStrokeWidth: 1,
            symbolFill: '#a4edba',
            symbolStroke: '#330033'
        }
    }
}
```

To change a legend item text color, use `labelFormatter` function:

```
legend: {
    labelFormatter: function() {
        return '<span style="color: ' + this.color + '">' + this.name + '</span>';
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/12pvu9Lj/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.symbol

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter

Comment: Thanks for your answer , In angular 7 getting compilation error, that 'color' properties does not exit in series

Comment: Hi @UIAPPDEVELOPER, You can try refer to some external color. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f0yw3bu4/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `labelFormatter` inside legend to change label text colors:

```
 labelFormatter: function() {
  return '<span style="color: ' + this.color + '">' + this.name + '</span>';
}
```

working fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/narkhedetusshar/61mqao9w/15/

Comment: Thanks for your answer , In angular 7 getting compilation error, that 'color' properties does not exit in series